# How to set up Spring Cloud Bus using ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I would like to use Spring Cloud Bus in my project to dynamic update the configuration.
We already have Apache ActiveMQ in our environment.
Is there any possible to use ActiveMQ instead RabbitMQ as the broker?
They are both one kind of AMQP server.

I set the dependency in pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It looks like a standard AMQP starter, not limited to RabbitMQ.
However, the following error log prompts when the config server starts up:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:439)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1083)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:350)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:648)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:205)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.MalformedFrameException: AMQP protocol version mismatch; we are version 0-9-1, server sent signature 0,1,0,0
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.protocolVersionMismatch(Frame.java:174)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:111)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:536)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any possible to use ActiveMQ instead RabbitMQ as the broker?

As far as I know ActiveMQ only provides AMQP 1.0 and the rabbit client is 0.9.1, so the answer is "no". If you provided a spring-cloud-stream binder for AMQP 1.0 or JMS or one of the other protocols in ActiveMQ, you might be able to use it that way (in the Brixton release of Spring Cloud). They don't exist out of the box though, so you'd have to write that bit yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.